# get current location of user in Ionic physical device (iOS build)

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, geolocation

I'm trying to get device's location in Ionic.
Earlier I was trying to get it through https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/

But, it keep giving me 'Only secure origins are allowed' error.

So, I moved the geolocation code to a Heroku app, located at https://location-for-houseq.herokuapp.com

The idea was to open the link in Ionic's in app browser, then store the location in localStorage, and access via Typescript code. But this is not working.

The code for geolocation is this

```
$(window).ready(function(){
console.log("Window ready")
function getLocation(){
    console.log('Getting location');
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        $('#output').html(JSON.stringify(pos));
      }, function() {
        // handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      },{enableHighAccuracy: true,maximumAge: 10000});
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      console.error('Browser doesn\'t support Geolocation');
    }
}
$(document).on('click','#trigger',function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    getLocation();
});
```

});

If anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong, or any Ionic based workaround for this, I'd be glad to try it out.